# How to handle server/request errors in flux?

Tags: flux

I've called an action creator from a component to create/edit a resource, which in turn sends an API request to a server. How should I handle cases where the server is down, or returns an error? I want any relevant components to be notified of the success/failure.

My current ideas are to:

1. Dispatch COMMENT_FAILED, COMMENT_SUCCESS actions to the comment store, which then notifies the components somehow?
2. Use promises within the initiating component to catch errors from the action call and respond/render them appropriately.

Which is better? Why?

This has been previously asked in [React+Flux: Notify View/Component that action has failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945788/reactflux-notify-view-component-that-action-has-failed), but the only proposed solution is to use Promises as in 2. I can certainly do that, but it seems... un-Flux-like.

Comment: what flux implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using Facebook flux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is create an error reducer specific to my container/component. For instance, if the user filed a login I would dispatch the error to my login reducer as follows.

```
export default function dispatchError() {
      return function(dispatch) {
           dispatch({
                type: 'LOGIN_ERROR',
                payload: 'You entered an incorrect password'
           });
      }
 }
```

Now in your instance this would be very similar. Anytime there is a failed request dispatch to your reducer.

Comment: Yes, that's very similar to what I was thinking. How would you handle cases where you have multiple of the same component on the same page? You would only want the component that initiated the action to respond to the the success/error dispatch. Perhaps promises are a better idea in that case?

Comment: I don't think Facebook's flux has reducers, but multiple stores. Should be similar enough though